# Make a multi-level appendix with cited equation, table and figure

Tags: appendices

**1. What I want**

I want to make the Appendix section as follows. Here, Appendix A and Appendix B

Appendix A are of the Chapter level, A.1 and B.1 are of the section level.

Title of Appendix A

A.1 Title

bla bla bla

A.2 Title

bla bla bla

Appendix B

Title of Appendix B

B.1 Title

bla bla bla

B.2 Title

bla bla bla

In the *Contents* the Appendix should be listed as

**Appendix A Title of Appendix A**

**A.1 Title**

**A.2 Title**

**Appendix B Title of Appendix B**

**B.1 Title**

**B.2 Title**

2. **The code I have used**

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
   \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{geometry}\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.7cm,right=2.5cm}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
   \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

   \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename 
   \ \thechapter}{15pt}{\Huge}
   \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-3\baselineskip}{20pt}[3.7cm]

   \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
   \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
   \hyphenpenalty=10000
   \tolerance=2500
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \raggedbottom

   \usepackage{cite}
   \usepackage{hyperref}

   \usepackage{nomentbl}
   \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
   \usepackage{enumitem,calc}

   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \usepackage{bigstrut}
   \usepackage{rotating}
   \usepackage{multirow}

   \usepackage{lscape}
   \usepackage{setspace}\linespread{1.6}
   \setlength\parskip{3pt plus 1.5pt minus 1.5pt}%paragraph

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{first chapter}
   ...
   \chapter{last chapter}

   \begin{appendices}

   \chapter{A Title}\label{appA}
   \section{A.1 Title}\label{appendixA1}
   \section{A.2 Title}\label{appendixA2}

   \chapter{B Title}\label{appB}
   \section{B.1 Title}\label{appendixB1}
   \section{B.2 Title}\label{appendixB2}

   \end{appendices}

   \end{document}
   ```

**My problems:**

The *word* "Appendices" occupies one whole page while Appendix A starts with a new page. But I want that Appendix A begins with a new page without the *word* "Appendices" occupying one whole page. In addition, the "Appendices" should not appear in the *Contents*, however, it now appears on the chapter level.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You don't have any chapter in your appendix. How can you hope to have a cross reference such as `appendix A`?

Comment: @Bernard, actually I do have some text, just forgot to indicate them, please see my update. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but you still don't have any appendix chapter. Only sections.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your reminding. Please see my update. I am not sure whether I should use `\begin{appendices}` and `\end{appendices}` or just `\appendix`. I found that with the former the word "Appendices" will occupy one whole page.

Comment: As to cross-references, the code you posted gives exactly what you're asking for, so there must be something else in your real code.

Comment: @Bernard it is my fault, now all the cross-references are shown in the desired form. The only problem is the _word_ "Appendices" occupies one whole page in the text while Appendix A starts with a following new page. But what I want is that Appendix A should begin with a new page without the preceding word "Appendices" in a whole page. In addition, the "Appendices" should not appear in the _Contents_, however, it now appears on the chapter level.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, if possible please give a quick review for my update.

Comment: try instead `\begin{appendices} ...\end{appendices}`use only `\appendix` on beginning of appendices.

Comment: You are requesting a `page` to be output for the appendices.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks a lot! By using `\appendix` instead that page disappears now. However, in the _Contents_ the appendices appear as **A** Title of Appendix A, and **B** Title of Appendix B. I want them to be **Appendix A** Title of Appendix A and **Appendix B** Title of Appendix B.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, could you please point out which line has requested a page for the appendices. I'm new to Latex and using other's template for my thesis. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @jsxs https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports Search for the word `page` in the code you posted.

Comment: @Johannes_B after search I believe it should be `\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}` and thanks for your useful link!